# Excel SQL Paste Formula down in column based on range of another column

Tags: excel, dynamic, count, range

I have a spreadsheet that will populate data in Column A beginning at A2 from a table.  Column A may be 10 rows or 150 Rows.  I have a calculation in column F.  I would like to Copy Down a formula in column F based on the number of Rows in Column A.

My code will copy a fixed range however I don't know how to make it dynamic based on the number of rows in column A.

```
Sheets("PriceAdjTemplate").Activate
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=(C2-E2)/C2"
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F350"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I would need to replace F350 with F & Number of rows in Column A Beginning with A2
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F350"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your coding approach, change the Selection.Autofill as follows:

```
Sheets("PriceAdjTemplate").Activate
Range("F2").Formula = "=(C2-E2)/C2"
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
```